# Issues passing parameters to stored procedure with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Seems to be a common question, but I cannot get any examples to work with my code.

Sorry in advance if this is trivial as I'm a DBA and not a developer.

I have a stored procedure that requires two parameters `LaborRate` and `EndDate`. `LaborRate` is a decimal data type and will get its variable from worksheet `BOMSum` and cell G1. `EndDate` is a date data type and will get its variable from worksheet `BOMSum` and cell G2. All of my attempts have failed even after looking through tutorials and other recommendations on this website.

Here's my very simple code I started out with that actually runs correct but runs without specifying any params:

```
Sub Execute_SP()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<ServerName>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=<DB_User>;Password=<pwd>"
conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "CostingInfo"

cmd.Execute
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Here's what I have now. I'm trying to pass two parameters `LaborRate` and `EndDate` from cell G1 and G2.

```
Sub Execute_SP()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim prm2 As ADODB.Parameter

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<ServerName>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=<DB_User>;Password=<pwd>"
conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = CostingInfo
prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@LaborRate", adDecimal, adParamInput)
prm1.Precision = 28
prm1.NumericScale = 4
cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
prm1.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Text
prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput)
prm2.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Text
cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
cmd.Execute
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

I've gotten errors regarding precision and object variable or with block variables not set. I'm stumped and very removed from VBA programming.

EDIT: After some suggestions by Rude Dawg, here's is my code now. I'm now getting a "Syntax error or access violation" error, which when is debugged points to the cmd.Execute section having the issue:

```
Sub Execute_SP()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim prm2 As ADODB.Parameter

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<ServerName>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=    <DB_User>;Password=<pwd>"
conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = CostingInfo
set prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@LaborRate", adDecimal, adParamInput)
prm1.Precision = 28
prm1.NumericScale = 4
prm1.Value = Sheets("BOMSum").Range("G1").VALUE
cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
set prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput)
prm2.Value = Sheets("BOMSum").Range("G2").VALUE
cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
cmd.Execute
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding the issue.

After bashing my head against my keyboard, I found out that I didn't have double quotes around my stored procedure name.

Here's my end result if anyone is interested:

```
Sub Execute_SP()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim prm2 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<ServerName>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=    <DB_User>;Password=<pwd>"

conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@LaborRate", adDecimal, adParamInput, 14,     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOMSumTbl").Range("G1").Value)
prm1.Precision = 28
prm1.NumericScale = 4
cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
Set prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, 7,     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOMSumTbl").Range("G2").Value)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
cmd.CommandText = "CostingInfo"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(adCmdStoredProc)
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with double brackets around my stored proc name: `[[spDistPOCheckOrderConfirmation_byLine]]`

Answer (score 1):

try this slight mod to your entry.

```
set prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@LaborRate", adDecimal, adParamInput)
prm1.Precision = 28
prm1.NumericScale = 4
cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
prm1.Value = Sheets("BOMSum").Range("G1").VALUE
set prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput)
prm2.Value = Sheets("BOMSum").Range("G2").VALUE
cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
```

also, why are you appending prm1 before you pulled the cell "G1" value?  Is that a slight typo?

Comment: Mr. Dawg, Thanks for your suggestion. That was indeed a typo. I've used your suggestion and it's throwing a "Subscript out of range" error. When I debug, it highlights this line of code: prm1.Value = Sheets("BOMSum").Range("G1").Value

Comment: you definitely have a sheet named 'BOMSum' correct?  Make sure the prm1 parameter has a .value attribute.  if both of those are true the only thing I can think of is try 'thisworkbook.sheets("BOMSum").Range("G1").value'

Comment: Yup. Definitely have a sheet called "BOMSum". After your changes it throws a syntax error or access violation error on the "cmd.Execute" section of the code.

Comment: I'm sorry that reaches outside of my range of knowledge.  I hope someone can chime in with a little more insight.  the only thing I can think of is that the cmd doesn't have an execute but I would think it does.  Maybe you need cmd.parameters.execute?  I have no idea at this point though, just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Not a problem! I appreciate your effort on this!